# CCLeaner wipe free space gone?

Tags: ccleaner

I am using CCleaner "wipe drive - wipe free space" at my home PC every time I take some work home. since a few days, I found the option is no longer available but I had problems finding any news about this. The only option left is "Entire drive (All data will be erased)"
Is this a new "feature" or did they just remove the option?

CCleaner version: v5.78.8558 (free home version)

[image]

Comment: You did not select a drive in the lower pane, select a drive and see if you get that option now.

Comment: yes, I tried that already. It does not show up

Comment: Update your question with a proper screenshot.  Indicate what version of CCleaner you are using

Comment: well obviously the latest or I would have asked. But I updated my post

Comment: @veritaS - It wasn't obvious otherwise I wouldn't have asked what version you were running.  In this case, it made a huge difference, since it was disabled due to the company receiving reports the feature was broken.

Answer (score 0):

> The only option left is "Entire drive (All data will be erased)" Is this a new "feature" or did they just remove the option?

Piriform Software disabled it.

> Wipe Free Space option disabled in this version
>
> We’re committed to providing the safest PC cleaner on the market. That’s why, after receiving reports that the ‘Wipe Free Space’ optional cleaning setting is erasing more than it should do in some cases, we have disabled it while we complete our investigations

Source:

- [CCleaner v5.78.8558](https://www.ccleaner.com/knowledge/ccleaner-v5788558)
- [Can't wipe hard drive version 5.78](https://community.ccleaner.com/topic/60248-cant-wipe-hard-drive-version-578/?tab=comments#comment-328094)

Comment: You could install CCleaner v5.77.8521 but the feature is broken and was disabled by the company.